# Reading list manager for scientfic papers

Tags: linux, information-management

Sometimes you stumble upon interesting papers (pdfs) or blog posts, but there is no time to read it right now.

My current strategy is to keep it in a tab in my browser and there it will stay basically forever until I decide to close all tabs, because there is simply to much stuff.

So the need for an app that helps me remember, prioritize and tag/search these articles is needed with the following features:

- save (links to) pdfs and web pages
- save additional notes
- tag/categorize/search
- order/prioritize in same way

I have tried using my reference management software, but it is a bit of a hassle to create a new bibtex entry and I found no good way to order the reading list.

I also tried bookmark services like pocket and instapaper, but again I found no way to create an ordered "read it later" list.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a browser plugin like "[Pocket](https://getpocket.com/)". This will save the link to the paper in the pocket dashboard and you can enrich this entry with your desired tags. You can also try "[Evernote](https://evernote.com/)", which would let you actually save the pdf in the cloud and gives more control over the organization as it lets you sort your material into notebooks (that are basically folders).

Comment: Thank you for your answer!  :)  Can you provide links to your recommendations?

Comment: I mentioned "pocket" in the apps I tried, but it is missing sorting features.
I will give Evernote a try.